# Parametros opcionales en Flask route

Tags: python, flask

Estoy trabajando con `Flask` y estoy intentando obtener 3 resultados desde una misma ruta, una obteniendo una petición tipo `GET`, otra obteniendo una petición tipo `POST` y otra recibiendo una url parametrizada como `@app.route("/<arg>")`.

Todo me funciona bien hasta que parametrizo la URL, esto es lo que he intentado hacer.

## Funciona:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['POST','GET'])
def main():
    
    if(request.method=='GET'):
       //DO SOMETHING.
       return render_template("index.html")
    elif(request.method=='POST'):
       //DO SOMETHING.
       return render_template("landpage.html")
```

Esta primera parte me funciona sin ningún problema, el problema viene al meter una url parametrizada opcional.

## No Funciona:

```
@app.route("/<arg>", methods=['POST','GET'])
def main(arg=None):


    if(arg != None):
       //DO SOMETHING.
       return render_template("args.html")
    elif(request.method=='GET'):
       //DO SOMETHING.
       return render_template("index.html")
    elif(request.method=='POST'):
       //DO SOMETHING.
       return render_template("landpage.html")
```

En cuanto intento acceder por 127.0.0.1:50000 me da NOT FOUND ERROR, pero en teoría el parámetro debería de ser opcional y debería funcionar, según me pareció entender en la documentación de Flask. Solo me funciona cuando hago algo como 127.0.0.1:50000/521

Error que muestra el navegador al acceder a 127.0.0.1:50000:

> **Not Found**
> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: Añade la salida del error completa

Comment: @JoseRodriguez en la consola de VSCode, tras hacer `flask run` no me devuelve ningún error. En el navegador me sale Error not found.

Comment: Has probado a quitar el elif de GET? a efectos practicos una peticion a la raiz sin argumentos es lo mismo que un GET (por defecto)

Comment: Lo que he probado ha sido hacer `if (argid... elif request.method==['POST'] ... else: por aquí el GET`

Comment: Prueba una cosa: Deja el main para tu raiz, y crea otra ruta con el argumento y crea otra funcion, por ejemplo `def argumento(arg):` y accedes a la variable arg desde dentro de la funcion. Flask deberia ser suficientemente listo como para enrutar main() or argumento() según intentes acceder. Al menos así es como me funciona a mi

Comment: @JoseRodriguez el en este caso es más aprender a hacer estas cosas, a encontrar una solución, sé cómo podría solucionarlo, pero no sé como solucionarlo con la condición de usar un solo método y una sola ruta. La solución más sencilla es añadir `@app.route("/"):` y con eso funciona sin cambiar nada, pero me gustaría entender el motivo de que no entre en la ruta si no se le envían parámetros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El parámetro es opcional solamente para la función, eso no indica que en las reglas de routing, sea opcional.

Cuando tú tienes

```
@app.route("/<arg>", methods=['POST','GET'])
def main(arg=None):
```

Estás diciendo que todas las url que coincidan con la expresión `/<arg>`, entrarán a la función `main(arg=none)`, `/anterior` coincide con la expresión, y toma `anterior` como valor de `arg` pero como `/` no coincide con dicha expresión, no entra.

Al hacer

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
@app.route("/<arg>", methods=['POST','GET'])
def main(arg=None):
```

Le estás diciendo que tanto `/` como `/<arg>` entran a la función, main, por lo tanto `/`, ahora sí coincide con la primera expresión, por lo que ahora, entrará en la función, al no tener un `arg` especificado, toma el default, en este caso `None`, para eso sirve ponerlo como parámetro opcional.

si dejaras la función

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
@app.route("/<arg>", methods=['POST','GET'])
def main(arg):
```

Te marcaría un error con `/`, dado que no se está pasando el parámetro `arg` a la función